# Getting function to_char(unknown, unknown) is not unique

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a repository which is supposed to fetch offers:

```
@Query("SELECT offer FROM OfferEntity offer " +
        "   JOIN offer.placeOwnership AS owner " +
        "   JOIN owner.place AS place " +
        "WHERE " +
        "   place.id = :placeId AND " +
        "   to_char(offer.offerDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') = to_char(:date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') ")
List<OfferEntity> getAllForDate(@Param("placeId") Long placeId, @Param("date") ZonedDateTime date);
```

However, this is not working as I get:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function to_char(unknown, unknown) is not unique
  Hint: Could not choose the best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 649
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2477) ~[postgresql-42.1.4.jar:42.1.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2190) ~[postgresql-42.1.4.jar:42.1.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300) ~[postgresql-42.1.4.jar:42.1.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428) ~[postgresql-42.1.4.jar:42.1.4]
```

I don't know what the problem is but it's obviously this part:

```
to_char(offer.offerDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') = to_char(:date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

How can I make this work?

If I remove the parameter `date`:

```
to_char(offer.offerDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') = '2018-10-07'
```

it is working but - obviously, this lacks a bit of flexibility.

Also:

```
'2018-10-07' = to_char(:date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

works.

---

There's more:

It's not working like this with `java.util.Date` either:

```
@Query("SELECT offer FROM OfferEntity offer " +
        "   JOIN offer.placeOwnership AS owner " +
        "   JOIN owner.place AS place " +
        "WHERE " +
        "   place.id = :placeId AND " +
        "   offer.offerDate = to_date(to_char(:date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) ")
List<OfferEntity> getAllForDate(@Param("placeId") Long placeId, @Param("date") Date date);
```

Comment: Your :date parameter has replaced by a string?

Answer (score 0):

you should refactor to

```
to_char(cast(:date as date), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```